# NN Output leans towards latest training examples

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to make my NN recognize "happy" and "sad" faces, hand-drawn in a 20x20 canvas. I'm using 400 input layer units, 100 hidden layer units, and 2 output units (happy/sad). The activation function for hidden & output layer is sigmoid.

I'm training the neural network progressively by manually drawing a face, selecting if it's happy or sad, and feeding the training sample to the neural network. Also, as I draw, the program shows the NN output dynamically.

The problem is that, as soon as I add a bunch of happy faces in a row, the output for "happy" raises up to almost 1. However, if I start adding sad faces, the output changes to happy=0.0241... sad=0.9988...

Sometimes, both outputs rise to almost one (happy = 0.99 / sad = 0.99).

It seems it should work that way, but in order to test the neural network, I started painting in the upper half of the canvas for HAPPY faces, and in the lower half for SAD faces. Same thing happens (the output leaning towards the latest samples), but I added like 50 training examples and the outputs don't seem to react to me painting in the lower / upper half at all.

I don't understand if I'm building the NN correctly or feeding the data correctly (it's just a 400-sized array with either 0.01 (white) or 0.99 (black)).

How can I prevent this behavior?

Neural Network class:

```
import scipy.special
import numpy
class NeuralNetwork:
def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
    # set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
    self.inodes = inputnodes
    self.hnodes = hiddennodes
    self.onodes = outputnodes

    # learning rate
    self.lr = learningrate

    # activation function
    self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

    # link weight matrices, wih and who
    self.wih = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hnodes, -0.5), (self.hnodes, self.inodes))
    self.who = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.onodes, -0.5), (self.onodes, self.hnodes))

    pass

# train the neural network
def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
    # convert inputs list to 2d array
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
    targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

    # calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
    # calculate the signals emerging from hidden layer
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

    # calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
    # calculate signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

    # error is the (target - actual)
    output_errors = targets - final_outputs

    # hidden layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden nodes
    hidden_errors = numpy.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

    # update the weights for the links between the hidden and output layers
    self.who += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)),
                                    numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs))

    # update the weights for the links between the input and hidden layers
    self.wih += self.lr * numpy.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_outputs)),
                                    numpy.transpose(inputs))

    pass

def query(self, inputs_list):
    # convert inputs list to 2d array
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

    # calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)

    # calculate the signals emerging from the hidden layer
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

    # calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
    # calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
    return final_outputs
```

Main code:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy
# scipy.special for the sigmoid function expit()
import scipy.special
# library for plotting arrays
import matplotlib.pyplot
from nn import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)

w = Canvas(frame, width=400, height=400, background="green")
w.pack()

canvasRectangles = []

for i in range(20):
    ls = []
    for k in range(20):
        x = 20*i
        y = 20*k
        ls.append(w.create_rectangle(x,y,x+20,y+20,fill="white"))
    canvasRectangles.append(ls)

label = Label(frame,text='Number pressed: N/A')
label.pack()

hdnLayer1Label = Label(frame,text="Hidden Layer 1",justify=LEFT,wraplength=300)
hdnLayer1Label.pack()

outLayerLabel = Label(frame,text="Output Layer",justify=LEFT,wraplength=300)
outLayerLabel.pack()


def clearCanvas():
    for i in range(20):
            for k in range(20):
                w.itemconfig(canvasRectangles[i][k],fill="white")


def key(event):
    if event.char is 'r':
        clearCanvas()
    else:
        if event.char is '1':
            label.config(text="SMILE: Happy")
        if event.char is '2':
            label.config(text="SMILE: Sad")
        global number
        number = event.char


def initNN():

    input_nodes = 400
    hidden_nodes = 100
    output_nodes = 2
    learning_rate = 0.3

    global n
    n = NeuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)


def queryNN(rectangles):
    unscaledInputs = getRectangleValues(rectangles)
    arr = numpy.array(unscaledInputs)
    scaledInputs = scaleInputs(arr)

    res = n.query(scaledInputs)
    return res


def trainNN(rectangles, desiredOuts):
    inputs = getRectangleValues(rectangles)
    arr = numpy.array(inputs)
    # Scale the inputs
    scaledInputs = scaleInputs(arr)
    global n
    n.train(scaledInputs, desiredOuts)
    pass


def getRectangleValues(rectangles):
    rectvals = []
    for col in range(20):
        for row in range(20):
            if w.itemcget(rectangles[col][row], "fill") == "black":
                rectvals.append(0)
            else:
                rectvals.append(1)
    return rectvals




def tab(event):

    desiredOuts = [0, 0]

    if number is '1':
        desiredOuts[0] = 1
        print("desiredSmile= HAPPY")
    if number is '2':
        desiredOuts[1] = 1
        print("desiredSmile= SAD")

    print(desiredOuts)
    trainNN(canvasRectangles, desiredOuts)
    clearCanvas()


def draw(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    if x <= 400 and y <= 400 and x >= 0 and y >= 0:
        squarex = int(translate(x, 0, 400, 0, 20))
        squarey = int(translate(y, 0, 400, 0, 20))
        if not squarex is 20 or not squarey is 20:
            w.itemconfig(canvasRectangles[squarex][squarey], fill="black")
            outLayerLabel.config(text="Output: " + repr(queryNN(canvasRectangles)))


def translate(value, leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax):
    # Figure out how 'wide' each range is
    leftSpan = leftMax - leftMin
    rightSpan = rightMax - rightMin

    # Convert the left range into a 0-1 range (float)
    valueScaled = float(value - leftMin) / float(leftSpan)

    # Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the right range.
    return rightMin + (valueScaled * rightSpan)


def scaleInputs(unscaledins):
    return (numpy.asfarray(unscaledins) / 1.0 * 0.99) + 0.01


initNN()

w.bind("<Button-1>", draw)
w.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw)
frame.bind("1",key)
frame.bind("2",key)
frame.bind("r", key)
frame.bind("<Tab>", tab)

frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()


'root.after(0,doWork)'
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How is this different to a question you did yesterday or the day before? Also, fix your indentation and put the complete code (imports missing)

Comment: Why do you care of how your network behaves on learning phase? Does it classify the faces wrong after the training is completed?

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel I made the question and left, so I couldn't add the source code.

Comment: @AlexeyR. There isn't a training set. I am training the network dynamically, i.e I draw, the network gives me a prediction, but I can choose to train the NN with the face just drawn (selecting if it's a sad or happy face). I guess I shouldn't query the network until I trained it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has a similar problem, I solved it by reducing the canvas resolution (from 20x20 to 7x7). I guess that such a high resolution needs much more training samples.
Also, I made a training set and iterated through it several times (about 8 epochs did the trick for me).

The solution is simple: if your inputs are more complex, you need much more training.